# Is it possible to specify which v-net AKS should put load balancers into?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

AKS creates it's own resource group and vnets when deployed, I am not sure if it is possible to specify which vnet AKS should deploy the load balancer into. I know we can specify which vnet and subnet to deploy clusters into and was wondering if we can do the same for the load balancers.

Answer (score 0):

No, as the ip of the load balancer must be in the same subnet as the cluster. But you can configure which ip that should be:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: internal-app
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-ipv4: 10.240.0.25
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: internal-app
```

That will create an internal load balancer and it will get the ip `10.240.0.25` assigned. Note that, as stated above, the ip must be in the same subnet as the cluster.

You can also specify which ip to use by setting the `service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-ipv4` to one of the subnet.

```
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-ipv4: 10.240.0.25
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

By that the loadbalancer will get the ip `10.240.0.25` assigned. Note that the ip must be in the same subnet as the cluster.

You can check if an ip address is available/unused with the az cli:

```
az network vnet check-ip-address -g MyResourceGroup -n MyVnet --ip-address 10.240.0.250
```

Also see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb#specify-an-ip-address)